# Inject Font Awesome token as build secret to .npmrc via Dockerfile from GitHub secrets

Tags: docker, github-actions, font-awesome, azure-container-registry, .npmrc

We currently use the Font Awesome library for fonts and icons in our application. It's registered inside the the `.npmrc` file as below:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/ 
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN}
```

Our goal is to retrieve the `FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN` from GitHub secrets for security purposes and inject into the Dockerfile.

As of today, a Docker image of the solution is created using a Dockerfile like mentioned below:

```
# base node image
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim as base

# set for base and all layer that inherit from it
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Install all node_modules, including dev dependencies
FROM base as deps

EXPOSE 3010

ADD package.json package-lock.json .npmrc ./

RUN npm install --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc
```

We use GitHub Actions for CI/CD purposes and Docker image that is created above using the Dockerfile is passed into the build process that is deployed to Azure container registry.

```
      - name: ' Build and push :latest + :tag (if "releaseToDev-")'
        run: |
            az acr login --name testdevacr  # DEV ACR
            az acr build --secret-build-arg --secret-build-arg 
            FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN=${{ secrets.FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN }} -t test-web-app:latest -t test-web- 
            app:${{steps.tag-result.outputs.result}} -r testdevacr -f Dockerfile .
```

The issue is that the `npm build` inside GitHub Actions fails with the following error message:

```
Step 8/22 : RUN npm install -g npm@10.2.0 --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc
 ---> Running in d6d81255b755
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 10.2.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.0` to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-10-04T07_23_59_609Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc' returned a non-zero code: 1
2023/10/04 07:24:37 Container failed during run: build. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: build: exit status 1
```

Any tips on how to pass the Font Awesome token in a way it is recognized?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/docker-and-private-modules), looks like the command `RUN npm install --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc` should be `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npmrc,target=/root/.npmrc npm install`. Apart from that, in your build step there are no trailing slashes for multiline commands in `az acr build` command. Also, the first `--secret-build-arg` is redundant.

Comment: --secret-build-arg is redundant because it was used for 2 variables, and I omitted their values. But we have solved it and have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

We could finally solve this with the use of ARG

We edited the Acr.yml file command by adding a `--secret-build-arg` variable as below.

```
az acr build --secret-build-arg FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN=${{ secrets.FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN }} -t test-web-app:latest -t test-web- 
app:${{steps.tag-result.outputs.result}} -r testdevacr -f Dockerfile .
```

Once we defined the variables inside the Dockerfile

```
ARG AZURE_ARTIFACTS_TOKEN
ARG FONT_AWESOME_TOKEN
```

it could be easily read and recognised and worked like a charm